# How to avoid VSCode from overwriting workspace settings while have settings sync on

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have (builtin) `settings sync` on in VSCode. For various workspaces I use the the workspace settings to give titleBar of each workspace a different color for easy recognition. However everytime I re-open a workspace (for which I set workspace settings for titleBar colorCustomizations) VSCode tries to overwrite the values in workspace `settings.json` into the ones used in user `settings.json`.

Example the workspace `settings.json` I set for the workspace:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#f558be",
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#ffffff",
    "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#f424ac",
    "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#cccccc",
    "editorGhostText.border": "#d94e4e",
    "editorGhostText.foreground": "#b95454",
  },
}
```

Which at re-opening are overwritten and thus changed into:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGhostText.border": "#d94e4e",
    "editorGhostText.foreground": "#b95454"
  },
}
```

I tried setting:

```
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
    "workbench.colorCustomizations"
  ],
```

in `User` settings, but that seems only works on user settings, as it does not solve my issue. The `settingsSync.ignoredSettings`, which might solve my issue, can not be set on `Workspace` settings.

I tried adding `vscode/` or `vscode/settings.json` to the `.gitignore` file of my project, but issue remains.

How can I avoid VSCode trying to overwrite my workspace settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I have installed an extension which already deals with UI colors called Peacock. It overrides the workspace settings. When I disable it the issue is gone. It looks nice actually, so better just start using it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [Settings precedence](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-precedence) "later scopes override earlier scopes", and Workspace comes after User.

Values with Object type are merged – like `workbench.colorCustomizations` then:

> If there are conflicting values, such as `editor.selectionBackground` in the example above, the usual override behavior occurs, with workspace values taking precedence over user values, and language-specific values taking precedence over non-language-specific values.

Does the problem go away if you disable Sync?

Are you using the latest version of VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I'm on latest VSCode version. The overriding behavior is correct (workspace overrules user settings), however my workspace settings are 'altered/ overwritten'. I does NOT happen when I switch off the Settings Sync.